# Android: Designing efficient data flow

Tags: android, service, broadcast, solid-principles

I am currently designing an application in which I have to download information about some movies in order to display the download information (trailer video, poster image, description... ).

I am a little bummed in what would be the a good design practice to maintain the data in the application for later use and also how to access it.

I currently have an IntentService (MovieService) that is responsible to download the movies information (it is stored on a remote server as json).

MovieService is also responsible to read the movies from the device storage if it is there and persisting it on the disk too.

It is therefore responsible for all the I/O related to the movies, but it feels like too much to me (maybe I am wrong?)

In order to keep the information available for the activities of my application, I have a MovieRepository that contains those movies.

My main problem comes here; when the service finishes downloading the movies, it puts them in the repository. Then, if any activity registered itself on the repository, it will get an event to say that some movies where downloaded and the activity can proceed to display them. But while I download the movies, I want to show a progress (in a progress bar) as well as basic offline errors. I use broadcasts sent from the service to carry that information out.

But I feel like I'm making it too complicated, **that I'm carrying the information coming from the service in two different ways.**

I thought about using my repository to carry the information from the service, by adding more listeners callbacks that would represent more atomic-like events on the data structure, but it still leaves me with problem of offline/online, that can't be really carried from the MovieRepository (doesn't have it's place there).

I also thought about binding my service to the activities that are calling it so I can get all the publicly available events and also have a repository that could maintain it; but it leaves the problem of a very heavy implementation on all the activities.

So, what would be a good way to design the services and the repository in a way that wouldn't be redundant, and would allow me to carry the informations that I need